# How to check for palindrome using while loop python

Tags: python, indexing, while-loop, palindrome

I'm trying to check for a palindrome using a while loop and indexing, return True or False. I know this can be done much simpler using a for loop or even just one line: 
    return num[::-1] == num
(num being the parameter inside the function)
[click for image of code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu3wb.png)

I'd love to complete this with a while loop if anyone could shed some light on what im doing wrong here would be great:)

By the way a palindrome is a word or phrase which can be read the same the reversed way around, example: level, racecar, rotavator etc

Comment: you need an if statement in your while loop to end the loop otherwise you will loop till you get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def palindrome(s):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(s) / 2:
        if s[i] != s[-i - 1]:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

this should do it.

Comment: i have a problem though when inputing s as an empty string, it says string index out of range

Comment: You can add a line in the beginning like this: if len(s) == 0 return False/True depending on what you'd like it to return

Answer (score 0):

```
str = input("Enter a string: ") #taking a string from user & storing into variable.
li = list(str) #converting the string into list & storing into variable.
ln = len(li) #storing the length of the list into a variable.
revStr = "" #defining an empty variable (which will be updated & will be final result to check palindrome).
i = ln - 1 #value of i will be used in loop.

while i >= 0: #here logic is to start from right to left from the list named "li". That means going from last to first index of the list till the index value is "0" of the "li" list.
    revStr = revStr + li[i] #concatenating & updating the "revStr" defined variable.
    i = i - 1 #decreasing the value of i to reach from the last index to first index.
str = str.lower() #converting value into lowercase string.
revStr = revStr.lower() #converting the final output into lowercase string to avoid case sensitive issue.

if str == revStr: #the two string is same or not?
    print(str, ", is PALINDROME!") #if same.
else:
    print(str, ", isn't PALINDROME!") #if not same.
```

Comment: Good, full code! But, would be perfect if you could add some explanation on what did the trick.

Comment: Hmm, ok i'm giving explanation. Wait few min. I'll get back to you.